# ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Working in virtual environment

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

[image]

Hello! As the image shows, I activate the env where I already installed Django. After that, I try to run python3 manage.py runserver and an error message appears, saying Django couldn't be imported.

I'm working on Windows 10.

I followed the steps given by Delicia Brummitt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages) but couldn't get it working.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.